# How to get country language in Symfony

Tags: symfony, twig, country

I'm customizing my error pages and I was wandering if it is possible to get the language of the country user directly in my template, without the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

```
{{ app.request.locale }}
```

## Edit

Ah i didn't understood the question but this is what you are looking for :

```
 $request->getPreferredLanguage($anArrayOfYourSupportedLanguages);
```

Then pass it to your twig.
fabpot answer :

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/symfony-devs/-2AwAQhlLLQ

Comment: Won't this just return my default langugae? Because I would really like if there was a way to get the used language according to the country the personne is in.

Comment: updated my answer.  getPreferredLanguage and pass it to your twig